# React Native Web navigation not working as expected

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

I've setup a minimal Expo React Native application with web support and have the following setup:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { Link, LinkingOptions, NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

function Screen1() {
  return (
    <View>
      <Link to="/screen-one">Screen 1</Link>
      <Link to="/screen-two">Screen 2</Link>
      <Link to="/screen-three">Screen 3</Link>
    </View>
  )
}
function Screen2() {
  return (
    <View>
      <Link to="/screen-one">Screen 1</Link>
      <Link to="/screen-two">Screen 2</Link>
      <Link to="/screen-three">Screen 3</Link>
    </View>

  )
}
function Screen3() {
  return (
    <View>
      <Link to="/screen-one">Screen 1</Link>
      <Link to="/screen-two">Screen 2</Link>
      <Link to="/screen-three">Screen 3</Link>
    </View>
  )
}

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

export default function App() {
  const linking: LinkingOptions = {
    prefixes: ['http://localhost:90006/'],
    config: {
      screens: {
        'screen-one': { path: 'screen-one' },
        'screen-two': { path: 'screen-two' },
        'screen-three': { path: 'screen-three' },
      }
    }
  };


  return (
    <NavigationContainer linking={linking}>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="screen-one" component={Screen1} options={{ title: 'Screen 1' }} />
        <Stack.Screen name="screen-two" component={Screen2} options={{ title: 'Screen 2' }} />
        <Stack.Screen name="screen-three" component={Screen3} options={{ title: 'Screen 3' }} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

When I use to navigate `props.naviation.navigate('some-location')` the browser history seems to get all messed up, but when I use `linkTo('/some-location')` it works as expected.

Why is the behaviour inconsistent with the two navigation methods?

Comment: i am facing navigation issue in the browser
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67604743/reactnavigation-5-0-browser-next-previous-button-not-enable/67605994#67605994