# ReactNavigation 5.0 browser next/previous button not enable

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation-v5, react-native-web

I have created a project using [React Native for Web](https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web)   and it is working fine in mobile but when I run into the web it does not enable the browser default next-previous button.

How to enable browser button and manage next previous in browser

// In App.js in a new project

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { View, Text,Button,Platform } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

const isWeb = Platform.OS === 'web';

function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Button onPress={() => linkTo('/Details')} title="Go to Details Screen" />
    </View>
  );
}


function Details() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
     <Text style={{fontWeight:'100',fontSize:30}}>Detail's Screen</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function App() {

  return (
    
    <NavigationContainer>
   
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="HomeScreen">
        <Stack.Screen name="HomeScreen" component={HomeScreen} options={{ headerShown: !isWeb}} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Setting" component={Setting} options={{headerShown:!isWeb}}/>
        <Stack.Screen name="Details" component={Details} options={{headerShown:!isWeb}}/>
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use "navigation" object that is part of the params to the Home Screen. Have a look at below code

```
function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Button onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Details');} />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: i want to use browser next-previous default button not custom one